# Flash Sprite loses focus on MOUSE_DOWN event

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

My `Sprite` class keeps losing focus when I click with the mouse - specifically after the MOUSE_DOWN event (before the click is complete).

I have set `mouseEnabled` to false on the children, no change. I added a listener for `FOCUS_OUT` and noticed that the `FocusEvent.relatedObject` property is NULL, which is confusing me - doesn't that mean there is no new focus target, the focus is just getting lost?

The exact sequence of events I get, by tracing them, as I click:

```
[FocusEvent type="focusOut" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 relatedObject=null shiftKey=false keyCode=0]
[MouseEvent type="mouseDown" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 localX=355 localY=362 stageX=360 stageY=367 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=true delta=0])
[MouseEvent type="click" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 localX=355 localY=362 stageX=360 stageY=367 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0]
```

Comment: can you post a short example of this?

Comment: Like what? It's part of my app which is a whole bunch of files. The `Sprite` does nothing special other than set a mask.

Comment: is your stage taking the focus perhaps? maybe a stage.mouseEnabled = false might do it.

Comment: Nope: "exception, information=Error: Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `mouseChildren = false;` on the sprite instead of `mouseEnabled = false;` on the children.  If the sprite's children have `mouseEnabled` set to `false`, none of the visible elements contained in your sprite are clickable, except for the shapes drawn directly in its own graphics. You would then actually click "through" the children and on the stage.

**[EDIT]:**

I've created a test to reproduce your problem.  You're right - the focus is mysteriously lost when a sprite is clicked on, even though one would expect this to actually set the focus on it.  The same is true for MovieClips, but not for TextFields.  Unpractical though that may be, you can work around it by adding a custom mouseDown handler:

```
private function onMouseDown (ev:Event) : void {
    if (stage.focus != sprite) stage.focus = sprite;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried that but no change. For reference the Sprite draws a single rectangle the full-size of the Sprite so that is being clicked on, but that's all that is there - I disabled adding any children so I'm just clicking on the spite on top of the background rect, drawn using Sprite.graphics.drawRectangle

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this and get back to you.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time. It's great to know this is not my app. I actually have a similar workaround now and I can't think of practical problems with it... but it sure is odd. Not sure if it's a bug or some nuance of the right functionality I haven't understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend any [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html) you have to set `tabEnabled = true;` . This will make your clicked upon object gain focus.

Be careful though:
If *tabEnabled is false*, but *mouseChildren is true*, then the stage.focus will be set to null.